# Server down (timeout) when optimize bundle of image (Image Optimize Plugin)

Tags: image, server, queue, plugin-imageoptimize, timeout

I try to use the [Image Optimize](https://nystudio107.com/docs/image-optimize/) plugin to optimize the image with default Craft Transform. There are lots of images to be optimized at the same time, I keep having the issue of server down. Here is the error message,

```
The process "'/usr/bin/php7.4' 'craft' 'queue/exec' '280426' '300' '1' '7380' '--color='" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

[image]

I have installed the [Async (Background) Queue](https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue), but doesn't seems to be helpful.

Is there any solution for this?

Craft: 3.6.13

Image Optimize: 1.6.33

Comment: Did you configure the plugin [as per the documentation](https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue#configuration-optional) as well as setting `'runQueueAutomatically' => false` in your `config/general.php` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#runqueueautomatically))?

Comment: The server is down even I add this line

Comment: Do you have very large images, or not much CPU available? It sounds like its timing out the server, but 300 seconds is a very long time... I'm quite surprised any image transforms that need doing are not done in that timeframe. Can you give specs on your hosting?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of images to be optimized, some folders have 50+ images, some have 500+ images. Currently, I'm optimizing per folder based, but the issue still there. Yes, it used 100% of the CPU usage. Is there any way to solve this besides increasing the CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        'my-module' => \modules\Module::class,
    ],
    'components' => [
        'queue' => [
            'ttr' => 3600,
        ],
    ],
];
```

to `config/app.php`.